# ShowMessage in Delphi XE3 DllMain

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-2007, delphi-xe3

DLL below is compiled with XE3.

```
library MyDLL;

uses System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Dialogs;

{$R *.res}

var
  II: Integer;

function Test: Integer;
begin
  Result := II;
end;

exports Test;

begin
  II := 5;
  ShowMessage('DLL prolog');
end.
```

When I call the function `Test()` from Delphi XE3 or Delphi 2007 program I get the correct result (5) in both cases. But the message "DLL prolog" is displayed only with Delphi 2007 program, not with Delphi XE3 program. Why?

**Edit**

And when I "run" dll from XE3 IDE with Delphi 2007 host `ShowMessage()` also does not work.

Comment: Did you try to use the standard windows [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead?

Comment: Yes `MessageBox` works ok !?

Comment: You know that there are serious restrictions on what you can do from DllMain?

Comment: I did not know, but I now found on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx) . Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is in this function:

```
function MessageDlgPosHelp(const Msg: string; DlgType: TMsgDlgType;
  Buttons: TMsgDlgButtons; HelpCtx: Longint; X, Y: Integer;
  const HelpFileName: string): Integer;
begin
  if TOSVersion.Check(6) and UseLatestCommonDialogs and
     StyleServices.Enabled and StyleServices.IsSystemStyle then
    Result := DoTaskMessageDlgPosHelp('', Msg, DlgType, Buttons,
      HelpCtx, X, Y, HelpFileName)
  else
    Result := DoMessageDlgPosHelp(CreateMessageDialog(Msg, DlgType, Buttons),
      HelpCtx, X, Y, HelpFileName);
end;
```

In some cases, depending on whether or not the host application has a comctl32 v6 manifest, different branches of the `if` statement are chosen.

If the `DoTaskMessageDlgPosHelp` branch is chosen, then the ensuing call to `TaskDialogIndirect` fails with `HRESULT` code `$80070057`. This is a Win32 error code, `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

If the `DoMessageDlgPosHelp` branch is chosen, then the dialog shows.

I'm not sure why `TaskDialogIndirect` is failing when called from a library initialization block, but I'm not entirely surprised. You are severely restricted in what can be done from `DllMain` and you should not be attempting to show dialogs from there.

Comment: Yes, this is DllMain restriction illustrated

Comment: ComCtl32.TaskDialogIndirect calls ComCtl32.CTaskDialog.Show, which calls DUser.InitGadgets, which calls DUser.ResourceManager.InitContextNL. The latter one explicitly checks if it is called from within DllMain, DUser.WinNT.IsInsideLoaderLock returns TRUE, thus the caller returns hard-coded 0x80070057, which pop up to retvalue of TaskDialogIndirect.

Comment: Try something like UseLatestCommonDialogs := False before calling ShowMessage from DllMain. If you want to write universal wrapper - try use NtDll.RtlIsThreadWithinLoaderCallout.

Comment: @Alex Don't show dialogs from DllMain. Also, please don't use QC. It's QualityPortal now.